# React navigation problem when authenticating

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-native-navigation

I am working on a small project to create a simple login page and a dashboard using react native. The idea is to simply insert your username and password which -then- should be authenticated using a MongoDB. Thereafter, the app should navigate to the dashboard. The thing is, I managed to create the login page and the navigation works well in the beginning before adding the authentication. but then, it stopped working as I expect. Here where the problem lies exactly in the code :

I have tried to add this to the Submission function as you can see so that it navigates directly when authentication the user, otherwise it will not. However, I got nothing in the end and the outcome was almost the same.

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props),
      (this.state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        acc: false
      });
  }
  Submission() {
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/auth", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({ acc: responseJson });
        console.log(this.state.acc);
        let x = this.state.acc;
        // console.log(x);
        if (x == "true") {
          // console.log("ok")
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
        }
      });
```

The problem could be simple as I am still in the very beginning but I cannot go forward and proceed with the code due to this issue. I hope that I can get some ideas on how to overcome this as it took me ages to solve it but I couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding catch block to the response, so that you could find what the error is. I guess the response would not be a proper JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this millions of  times but it didn't work. All commands don't seem to work properly in catch block nd I don't know why.

Comment: You need try test it with a postman.

Comment: I did test it with postman, and it's working.

Comment: What do you get when you ```console.log(responseJson)```?

Comment: I get a return value from the back-end ( response). so if the mail and password match a correct and valid value in the database it returns true.